# How to have a default tab open in this accordion and have it close the tab when another is opened?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, accordion

I'm not very good at javascript and I am just using the basic code from w3. I'm trying to put an accordion on my website that lists some of the services in categories and I would like one tab to always be expanded.

Here is my current code:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */

button.accordion {
  background-color: #3bb7df;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 54px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #2894b7;
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '+';
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-shadow: none;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "–";
}


/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */

div.panel {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

div.panel li {
  list-style: none;
  border-top: solid 1px #ddd;
}

div.panel li:hover {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}

div.panel a {
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

div.panel i.fa-angle-right {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

All of the default code and be found on the w3 site for the accordion.

I want the first tab to be open by default, and then if another tab is opened, close the other open tab.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: No need. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Opening first tab by default

To open the first tab (or any other) by default, simply invoke the `click()` method on the desired accordion index. This can be done at the end of your JavaScript:

```
acc[0].click(); // <-- Invoke the onClick for the first tab.
```

---

#### Always keep one tab expanded

To keep one accordion tab open at all times, radio button style, you'll need to save a reference to the last clicked accordion item, then perform some logic to close it before opening the new accordion menu.

See below for the working example.

---

#### Complete Example

I've cleaned up your code a bit by moving the operations to seperate functions, and including the `opening first tab by default` and `always keep one tab expanded` changes.

There is an `alwaysOneOpen` variable on line 4 of the JS that you can toggle to change the behavior. Currently it is true, which stops you from having all tabs closed. If you change this to false, you'll be able to close the tab by clicking on it.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
var last;
var alwaysOneOpen = true;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    // If the same accordion was clicked, toggle it
    if (last === this && !alwaysOneOpen) {
      toggleAccordion(last);
    } else {
      // If another accordion was open, close it
      if (last) {
        closeAccordion(last);
      }
      // Open clicked accordion
      last = this;
      openAccordion(last);
    }
  };
}

var closeAccordion = function(acc) {
  acc.classList.remove("active");
  var panel = acc.nextElementSibling;
    panel.classList.remove("active");
  panel.style.maxHeight = null;
}

var openAccordion = function(acc) {
  acc.classList.add("active");
  var panel = acc.nextElementSibling;
    panel.classList.add("active");
  panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
}

var toggleAccordion = function(acc) {
  last.classList.toggle("active");
  var panel = last.nextElementSibling;
  panel.classList.toggle("active");
  if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
  } else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
};

last = acc[0];
toggleAccordion(last);
```

```css
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */

button.accordion {
  background-color: #3bb7df;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 54px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #2894b7;
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '+';
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-shadow: none;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "–";
}


/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */

div.panel {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

div.panel li {
  list-style: none;
  border-top: solid 1px #ddd;
}

div.panel li:hover {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}

div.panel a {
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

div.panel i.fa-angle-right {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The click only toggles one of the doms. What the op wants is one of the dom to always have active class

Comment: I'm sorry for being so stupid with Javascript, but I can't figure out how to combine the two codes. The first one worked fine and kept the tab open, but the second code didn't open anything.

Answer (score 0):

Think about storing the *index* of the current open tab in a number variable. Then, remove the `"active"` class of `acc[index]` when any tab is clicked on.

Of course, you should store the index *after* you deactivate `acc[index]` so you won't deactivate the item being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify if a jQuery solution was acceptable but I provided one here. I can rework to get vanilla JS if that is what you need.

Also note I simplified the logic for the 'scrollHeight' by using the inherit attribute of `max-height`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.accordion').on('click', function() {
  
    //remove 'active' from all items first
    $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
    
    // now add 'active' to the one clicked
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  })

  //change to whichever number you want active on load
  $('.accordion:nth-of-type(2)').click();

})
```

```css
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */

button.accordion {
  background-color: #3bb7df;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 54px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #2894b7;
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '+';
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-shadow: none;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "–";
}


/* this will adjst the max-height for active items*/

.accordion.active+.panel {
  max-height: inherit;
}


/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */

div.panel {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

div.panel li {
  list-style: none;
  border-top: solid 1px #ddd;
}

div.panel li:hover {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}

div.panel a {
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

div.panel i.fa-angle-right {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr/>
<div> <code>.accordion.active + .panel {
    max-height:inherit;
}</code></div>
```

Comment: This works fine except for that the minus and plus sign do not change properly.

Comment: oh i forgot to add those. i will modify answer

Comment: Just got back from lunch and modified my answer, amazing how you can think clearly after you eat. I simplified the logic by adding a CSS line `.accordion.active + .panel {
    max-height:inherit;
}`